# Conditional tab view

Tags: conditional, logic, user-interface

I'd like to create a tabview with conditions on it, rather than put the tabview inside an If statement, to reduce the length of my code. i.e.

```
switcher=False
TabView[{
  "a" -> Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 10}],
  Evaluate@If[switcher, "b" -> Plot[x^3, {x, 0, 10}]],
  "c" -> Plot[x^4, {x, 0, 10}]
  
  }]
```

Trouble is that when I run this It creates a Tab where the Plot is still visible for x^3, any suggestions on how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

nevermind, finally realized using

```
switcher=False
TabView[{
  "a" -> Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 10}],
  If[switcher, "b" -> Plot[x^3, {x, 0, 10}],Nothing],
  "c" -> Plot[x^4, {x, 0, 10}]
  
  }]
```

does the trick